# What is the way for a has many relationship in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-relations

I got a database table 'books', and a table 'reviews'. One book can contain many reviews (one-to-many). I want the data returned in a nested multidimensional array, but I get all the different rows returned with a JOIN query. Isn't this very performance and bandwidth inefficient? The server (NodeJS) needs to download alot of duplicate data. Is there another way to structure a hasmany relationship in MySQL, without downloading duplicate data? Or need I to switch to PostgreSQL for example?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.) Also take a look at [mcve].

Comment: I understand the inefficiency you are talking about. However, you could use simple persistence layer on top of the RDBMS (local or very close to it) to perform the JSON rendering, compression, etc. to save bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the duplication of values from the `books` table, then run two queries:

```
SELECT ... FROM books WHERE id = ?;
```

Then a separate query:

```
SELECT ... FROM reviews WHERE book_id = ?;
```

*Not every operation must be done in a single SQL query!*

Comment: Is there a way to combine these queries in one query? Otherwise I need to initialize the connection twice, that is inefficient for the performance.

Comment: You don't need to do that. You can run multiple SQL queries using a single connection.

Comment: You could run a union query to get both in one query. But I agree with @bill karwin

Comment: @DanieldeVogel Don't fall into the trap of premature optimization. The general consensus is to worry about it when you have to.

Comment: As Bill pointed out, you do not need to open a new connection for every query; that is actually usually a bad idea performance wise as it can often* take longer to open a connection than it can to perform a query. (often* depending on api used, many support "connect pooling", in which case you are often reusing a previous connection anyway). _If you want to limit connections, then connect, do all your work, then disconnect when you are done; a hint at this kind of use is expected is that connections are often referred to "sessions"._